# changing the order of items in a list

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with plain text. This file contains a list like this:

```
@"Joe", @"211",
@"Bob Nelson", @"132",
@"Jack Sierra", @"3422",
@"Walt Robert", @"14",
```

The list goes on and on with thousands of names... I need to switch the elements order and transform this list to

```
@"211", @"Joe",
@"132", @"Bob Nelson",
@"3422", @"Jack Sierra",
@"14", @"Walt Robert",
```

How do I do it from terminal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one will work with strings with spaces in it:

```
sed 's/\(@"[^"]*"\), \(@"[^"]*"\)/\2, \1/' input.txt
```

**How it works:**

sed - (s)tream (ed)itor will execute (s)ubstosute command on each line of input, 

and replaces `\(@"[^"]*"\), \(@"[^"]*"\)` with the `\2, \1`.

The `\2` means second match (from the second braces)
The `\1` means first match (from the first braces).

Braces must be escaped, so we have `\(` and `\)`. Inside we look for `@` character, then `"` character and then `[^"]` any characters different than `"` repeated anytime and then the `"` character.

Then we expect `,` comma followed by the space and similar second group for the `\2`.

Comment: Yessssssssssssssssssssssss!!!!!!!!!!! You are awesome!!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Match the first field, the separator and the second field, and print them out in reverse order. Assuming there can't be commas inside the double quotes:

```
sed -e 's/\(.*,\)\( \)\(.*,\)/\3\2\1/'
```

Awk is clumsier here because of the comma at the end of the line. Nonetheless you can do the swap by treating comma plus space or `/ +/` as the field separator.

```
awk -F ', ' '{print $2 " " $1 ","}'
```

If there can be commas inside the quotes, you'll need to match the fields in a way that takes your quote escaping rules (if any) into account.

Comment: Your awk implementation produces double comma separator. Should be `awk -F ', ' '{print $2 " " $1 ","}'`